# Limit of $A_j\cap B_j$ in the Hausdorff distance, when $A_j\rightarrow A$ and $B_j\rightarrow B$.

Tags: analysis, hausdorff-distance

Let $A_j$, $B_j$, $A$ and $B$ be sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $A_j \rightarrow A$ and $B_j \rightarrow B$ both in the Hausdorff distance (induced by the usual Euclidean metric in $\mathbb{R}^n$) and $A_j\cap B_j\neq \emptyset$ for all $j\in\mathbb{N}$. If $A_j \cap B_j \rightarrow E$ for some set $E\subset \mathbb{R}^n$, then do we have $E\subset A\cap B$?

It is known that $E\neq A\cap B$ in general, but the counterexample I could only find falls under the case $E\subset A \cap B$. So is it true in general?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  It can help to notice that two sets which are relatively dense have Hausdorff distance zero.  (Relatively dense means that for any point of one and any $\varepsilon > 0$ radius open ball of that point, there is a point of the other within that ball.  "Dense" isn't the right idea because we do not require one set to be a subset of the other.)

Let $A = B = A \cap B$ be the rational points in the unit ball of $\mathrm{R}^n$.  Let $A_j = B_j = E$ be the unit ball in $\mathrm{R}^n$.  Clearly, the Hausdorff distance between $A_j = E$ and $A$ is zero (any $\varepsilon > 0$ neighborhood of one contains the other), so $A_j \rightarrow A$ and likewise $B_j \rightarrow B$.  Then $E \smallsetminus (A \cap B)$ is the set of points in the unit ball with at least one irrational coordinate, so is definitely nonempty, so $E \not \subseteq A \cap B$.

Comment: Thanks! This brings me to think that if $A_j$, $B_j$, $A$ and $B$ are all closed sets (or compact sets to simplify the matter), then we may have $E \subset A \cap B$. Still I am guessing, and could be wrong. Anyway thanks for the comment!